# Переключение radiobutton на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть такой код:

```js
var inner = document.querySelector('.inner'),
  itemDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box-style');

inner.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 var target = e.target;

 if(target.tagName == 'LABEL') {

  itemDiv.forEach(function(item){
   item.classList.remove('active');
  });

  var targetDiv = document.querySelector(target.getAttribute('data-target'));

  targetDiv.classList.add('active');
 }

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Assets
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Colors
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Fonts
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Stylings
--------------------------------------------- */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /*display: -webkit-box;*/
    /*display: -moz-box;*/
    /*display: box;*/
    /*display: -webkit-flex;*/
    /*display: -moz-flex;*/
    /*display: -ms-flexbox;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*-webkit-box-pack: center;*/
    /*-moz-box-pack: center;*/
    /*box-pack: center;*/
    /*-webkit-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-moz-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-ms-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-o-justify-content: center;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    /*-ms-flex-pack: center;*/
    /*-webkit-box-align: start;*/
    /*-moz-box-align: start;*/
    /*box-align: start;*/
    /*-webkit-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-moz-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-ms-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-o-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-ms-flex-align: start;*/
    background-color: #CCCC33;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;

}

.body-wrap{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/*@media (min-height: 580px) {*/
    /*!*body {*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-o-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-flex-align: center;*!*/
    /*!*}*!*/
/*}*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.invoice {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    margin: 50px 0;
    padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
    /* float: left; */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
    float: right;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: "";
    height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
    content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
    color: #b7bcc3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
    background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.inner h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
    min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.item label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.item label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.item input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #CCCC33;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 19px;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.box-style {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.box-style p {
    line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style span {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="body-wrap">
 <div class="container">
  <form class="invoice">
 <header>
  <section>
    <h1 class="invoice-title">Выберите способ оплаты</h1>
  </section>
 </header>
 <main>
  <section class="inner">
   <div class="item">
    <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
    <label for="sub1" data-target=".form-one"><span>Оплата услуг по договору</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
    <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Госпошлины</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="box-style form-one">
    <span><input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя:"></span>
    <span><input type="text" placeholder="Ваше фамилия:"></span>
    <textarea name="form" placeholder="Напишите ваше сообщение"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="box-style form-two">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti corrupti cupiditate maxime eos eveniet, ipsa ex nisi vero recusandae dolorum modi eius totam soluta, dolorem! Numquam eos commodi unde nam?</p>
   </div>
  </section>
 </main>

    <footer>
    <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить онлайн</button>
    </footer>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Логика такая, в зависимости от выбранного радиобаттона, показывать соответствующий блок.

Я здесь сделал через делегирование, то есть на родителя повесил обработчик. Тут в label есть data-target с тем блоком который надо показать. Но внутри label есть еще span, и вот по клику на нем ничего не происходит, я понимаю в чем причина, но как сделать правильно не совсем понимаю.

Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как мне сделать, чтобы кликая и на span внутри label тоже появлялись соответствующие блоки. Я знаю один способ, но это получится просто дубликация того же кода. Я надеюсь я доступно изъяснил свою проблему, а то это у меня не всегда хорошо получается)

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в том, что вы ищите элемент по тегу `label`, а когда нажимаете на `span`, то оно уже не воспринимает его как `label`. Вам нужно именно нажатие на сам элемент

```js
var label = document.querySelectorAll('label'),
    itemDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box-style');

label.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    itemDiv.forEach(function(item){
      item.classList.remove('active');
    });

    var targetDiv = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('data-target'));

    targetDiv.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Assets
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Colors
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Fonts
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Stylings
--------------------------------------------- */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /*display: -webkit-box;*/
    /*display: -moz-box;*/
    /*display: box;*/
    /*display: -webkit-flex;*/
    /*display: -moz-flex;*/
    /*display: -ms-flexbox;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*-webkit-box-pack: center;*/
    /*-moz-box-pack: center;*/
    /*box-pack: center;*/
    /*-webkit-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-moz-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-ms-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-o-justify-content: center;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    /*-ms-flex-pack: center;*/
    /*-webkit-box-align: start;*/
    /*-moz-box-align: start;*/
    /*box-align: start;*/
    /*-webkit-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-moz-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-ms-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-o-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-ms-flex-align: start;*/
    background-color: #CCCC33;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;

}

.body-wrap{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/*@media (min-height: 580px) {*/
    /*!*body {*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-o-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-flex-align: center;*!*/
    /*!*}*!*/
/*}*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.invoice {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    margin: 50px 0;
    padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
    /* float: left; */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
    float: right;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: "";
    height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
    content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
    color: #b7bcc3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
    background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.inner h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
    min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.item label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.item label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.item input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: #CCCC33;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 19px;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.box-style {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.box-style p {
    line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style span {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="invoice">
      <header>
        <section>
          <h1 class="invoice-title">Выберите способ оплаты</h1>
        </section>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="inner">
          <div class="item">
              <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub1" data-target=".form-one"><span>Оплата услуг по договору</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
              <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Госпошлины</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-one">
            <span><input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя:"></span>
            <span><input type="text" placeholder="Ваше фамилия:"></span>
            <textarea name="form" placeholder="Напишите ваше сообщение"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-two">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti corrupti cupiditate maxime eos eveniet, ipsa ex nisi vero recusandae dolorum modi eius totam soluta, dolorem! Numquam eos commodi unde nam?</p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>

      <footer>
        <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить онлайн</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я понял, спасибо большое за помощь.